# How to show time with AngularJS date filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datefilter

I want to show my time as AM and PM, is it possible with angular date filter. I have tried the below code but doesn't  work for me.

```
<div>{{ '12:31:07' | date:'HH:mm' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a custom filter:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div>{{ '12:31:07' | time }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('time', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, arg) {
        var parts = input.split(':');
        var date = new Date(0, 0, 0, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        return $filter('date')(date, arg || 'mediumTime');
    };
}]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33868/

**Or use default filters:**

try:

```
<div>{{ '12:31:07' | date:'mediumTime' }}</div>
```

or

```
<div>{{ '12:31:07' | date:'shortTime' }}</div>
```

You can also try `'medium'` or `'short'` for date filter

Refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @byteC0de check now.

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular documentation for date filter, the date argument should be in a valid format.

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

So, you need to format your time string beforehand. For example;

```
<div>{{ '2017-09-04T12:31:07' | date:'h:mma' }}</div>
```

will give you the required result.